# Difference between DART Isolate and Thread (Java,C#)

Tags: dart, dart-isolates

For me The DART Isolate looks like a Thread (Java/C#) with a different terminology. In which aspect Isolate differs from a Thread?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Threads use shared memory, isolates don't.

For example, the following **pseudocode** in Java/C#

```java
class MyClass {
  static int count = 0;
}

// Thread 1: 
MyClass.count++;
print(MyClass.count); // 1;

// Thread 2:
MyClass.count++;
print(MyClass.count); // 2;
```

This also runs the risk of the shared memory being modified simultaneously by both threads.

Whereas in Dart,

```dart
class MyClass {
  static int count = 0;
}

// Isolate 1: 
MyClass.count++;
print(MyClass.count); // 1;

// Isolate 2:
MyClass.count++;
print(MyClass.count); // 1;
```

Isolates are isolated from each other.  The only way to communicate between them is to pass messages.  One isolate can listen for callbacks from the other.

Check out the [docs here](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/dart-up-and-running/contents/ch03.html#ch03-dartisolate---concurrency-with-isolates) including the "isolate concepts" section.

Comment: Hi, how can we view isolates from an operating system perspective? Is it similar to creating a new sub process?